# Raspberry pi ethernet light blinking a color when connected to laptop

Tags: pi-4, ethernet, raspberry-pi-os, ethernet-port, openwrt

I have received a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, and have been using it for several weeks. I had installed OpenWRT(21.02.1) on one of my MicroSD cards and had put it into my pi. I don't have an external monitor, so I run headless ssh via ethernet connected to my laptop. This time, the lights to the bottom left and right of the ethernet port of the pi are flashing green or red(sorry, I'm color blind) for about 5 seconds on, and 10 seconds off. I have tried switching power sources, ethernet cables(also I have made sure that they are plugged in correctly), MicroSD cards(without OpenWRT), and restarting both computer and pi.

Sorry if I wasn't previously clear about my problem, but it is that the ethernet connection between my computer and raspberry pi is disconnecting for 10 seconds after 5 seconds of being connected.

I don't really know what is happening, and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: does your laptop get an IP address from the pi?

Comment: Only when the light is on.

Comment: Also, my mom has just told me that on the left is yellow, and on the right is green. Idk if that helps at all.

Comment: bad ehternet cable perhaps

Comment: I literally stated that I had tried switching ethernet cables. The chances of having 3 suddenly bad ethernet cables are quite slim.

Comment: Sorry if I came off as rude, thank you for trying to help.

Comment: sorry - I must've missed that detail - my bad

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't too clear. My ethernet on my raspberry pi is connecting and disconnecting every 5 and 10 seconds.

Comment: please update your question,  problem description belongs in the question, not in comments

Comment: the laptop may be having a problem

Comment: Now how would I go about fixing that, or even diagnosing the problem, or even finding the problem?